# Access AWS S3 data via Web Identity From GCP without using keys

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, service-accounts, google-cloud-composer, assume-role

I want to access the data residing in a AWS s3 bucket from GCP Cloud Composer Environment's Service Account.

I followed this [link](https://blog.doit-intl.com/assume-an-aws-role-from-a-google-cloud-without-using-iam-keys-55012b0fa74a). But this also uses the key creation inside.

Is there a way to connect to AWS S3 from GCP via roles only?

Comment: How would you authenticate to AWS to prove that you are entitled to access the data stored in Amazon S3? How would AWS know that you are entitled to access a particular bucket?

Comment: cant we do it via aws iam web identity roles only? As we are mapping the google composer unique id to aws iam web identity role, aws shld be able to provide the access to s3 right? why do we have to again retrieve the aws access key and secret key like in the link? or is there any way to connect to aws s3 from goolge cloud composer?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Google Cloud Composer, but if you have some code that authenticates via a web identity by calling [AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity - AWS Security Token Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/API_AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity.html), then the API call will return a set of temporary IAM credentials. You would use those temporary credentials to access the data from Amazon S3.